# Use of 'do' in interrogative of Present tense

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

We say that "**Do** we have class today?"

Can we say that "**Do** there is class today?".Or,we must say "Is there class today?".

Comment: Please look at this previous question on this site: [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140154/when-to-use-does-and-is-while-starting-the-interrogative-sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140154/when-to-use-does-and-is-while-starting-the-interrogative-sentence)

Answer (score 2):

We never use **do** when making a question about a sentence that uses *to be*.  When you make a question about a *to be* statement, you use *to be* in the question.

For example,
**He is tall. : Is he tall?**
NOT
*Does he is tall?*

or

**There is class today. : Is there class today?**
NOT
*Does there is class today?* (or *Do there is class today?*)

We only use *do* when making a question about a sentence that uses another verb that isn't *be*, *have*, *shall*, *will*, *may*, *must*, or *can*.

For example:
**He drinks beer. : Does he drink beer?**